# JQuery custom selector

Tags: jquery, function, arguments, selector

I asked a question previously but I realized it's too confusing.  Basically I need to come up with a way to write a selector that behaves like the following:

for each element in this '' container, search to see if that element has a class of apple OR banana OR cranberry OR dragonfruit.  If it does then append this '.style' class to THAT element.

The twist is, all the classes that I'm checking for are dynamic.  I need a flexible way to insert different classes to search for in the selector.

```
For example:
Let's say I have one selector that reads:
For each element in '<div>', does element have banana OR dragonfruit.

But another selector would be different:
For each element in '<div>', does element have cranberry.
```

See so basically I need a dynamic selector that not only changes what it searches for, but also changes the length of the search list.  Some searches only need one filter, some need multiple.

TLDR: Is there a way to write:

`$(.divContainer).hasClass(x or y or z or w or....)`  where x, y, z, w.... are different class names that are generated dynamically.  How can I do this?!  I was thinking of using function calls in place of x, y, z.... basically using functions inside the .hasClass arguments

Comment: Don't ask a new question, edit your original question to clarify it.

Comment: I think what you want is `.is(".x,.y,.z")`.

Comment: or since you want to add a class `.filter('.x, .y, .z').addClass('style')`

Answer (score 0):

You could define a javascript function like this:

```
function hasAnyClasses(possibleClasses) {

    var container = $('.divContainer');

    $(possibleClasses).each(function(idx, el) {
        if (container.hasClass(el)) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Then call it with an array of possible classes, which you can generate dynamically:

```
if (hasAnyClasses(['x', 'y', 'z'])) {
    // has either class 'x' or class 'y' or class 'z'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/FEz3F/ for an example. Jquery selector can accept multiple elements to select separated by a comma.

The jquery code above:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var targetDiv = $('.container');
    searchElement(targetDiv, '.class1, .class2');           
    function searchElement(div, className)
    {
        $(div).find(className).each(function()
        {
            // ...
        });
    }                   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function like this,

```
function checkSelector(selectionList){
      $(selectionList).each(function(index, sel) {
                      if (container.hasClass(sel)) {
                            return sel;
                 }

}
```

Then use switch to evaluate and apply your code.

```
switch (checkSelector(['apple', 'banana'])) {
         case ('apple'):
                 //Code for apple class
                        break;
         case ('banana'):
                 //code for banana     
                        break;

         default:
               break;
}
```